# Calculate User Score using Peerindex API

Tags: php

To calculate user score using Peerindex  API, I have download this library:

```
https://github.com/nixilla/peerindex-api-consumer
```

When I tried to implement the example.php file located in the library folder, I am having the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Buzz\Browser' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\...
```

Did anyone already have this problem in the past? Any idea about how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package uses [`composer`](http://getcomposer.org/) to resolve external dependencies. You'll have to take the following steps before executing the example:

```
# download composer.phar
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
# install external deps
php ./composer.phar install
# update depencies (important)
php ./composer.phar update
```

Then open `example.php` in a text editor and replace `YOUR_KEY_HERE` by your API key.

Now you can execute the example

```
php example.php
```

Comment: Thanks, it is past 1 am here, gotta try when up in the morning.